# Bootstrap 3: images not resizing correctly in columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve the layout below, but my HTML isn't working correctly. Can someone tell me why it's not working?

```
<div id="technologies-skills">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="header">TECHNOLOGIES & SKILLS</h3>

            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                    <div class"col-md-1">
                        <img src="images/logos/android_logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block" alt="Android Logo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- container -->
</div> <!-- technologie-skills -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing some divs. Whenever you need to subdivide, do it in a row. When you're inside a row, everything (by default) is divided by 12 (in Bootstrap 3).

http://jsfiddle.net/emptywalls/8JvNT/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">left column</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">a</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">b</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">c</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">d</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">e</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">f</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">g</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">h</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">i</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">j</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">k</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">l</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! any reason why using `col-xs` vs `col-md`?

Comment: Oops sorry, I should have mentioned. I switched to the `col-xs` just for display/debugging in JSFiddle. Using `col-md` will work the same. You're welcome very much! Glad I could help. Please be sure and accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You are also missing "=" on classes

```
<div class"col-md-1">
```

should be: `<div class="col-md-1">`